# How to Convert HTML file TO GIF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am creating wait Cursor using CSS and google Js file.

Now I want convert That HTML file into GIF file...

Because I am using other JS file in my project so some page is conflict with google js file.

This is the link of my HTML page which I want to convert.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_r9LchWcj7zMnQtdnRUaC1DUjA/edit

Comment: HTML to GIF ?? what are you upto ??

Comment: Erm, would PrintScreen work?

Comment: Above Link of HTML has jquery code as well as CSS which is require ii run successfully ...
You can download that file and open in Browser so you can get Effect of Wait Cursor.....

Comment: Html2Image api  https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/

Comment: So I wnat to convert that HTML to GJI file, So that i can Put that GIF in my Project all page for Wait...
and Not conflict with my js...

Comment: @Vld - print screen will have browser included in it

Comment: @Vid Printscreen work but I need Effect of the wait Cursor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is with a screen capture software. Create a video of the loader, then clip it to one cycle. Then, if you have a Mac, download the [Gifrocket app](http://www.gifrocket.com/), which converts the video to a gif. I had a rough go at it, and this was the result:

[image]

Comment: Really it is most useful to me...:)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar when I needed to convert a piece of Rich Media Ad to GIF. I used this very useful and free program called ScreenToGif. Here's the link for it:

http://www.screentogif.com

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do the below .. Its a bit weird, but I assume that will work for you.

Do the below steps.

1. Download and install a screen capture software, for instance, **[Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)**.
2. Run your HTML along and enable the Video screen capture/ image sequence screen capture.
3. Open Photoshop, import the video/image sequence of the HTML that you have video captured which is having the wait cursor effect for which you need the GIF.
4. Save for web/export to the gif format.

This is how you can get what you are looking for, as HTML to GIF converter sounds impractical to achieve what you want.

Hope this helps.